# Inverse of sum of fractions

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm interested in the inverse of a finite sum of fractions.  eg:

$$ \large{\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b_i} }}$$

For $a_i, \ b_i \in \mathbf{R}$.  Specifically, can this be expressed in terms of a determinant or trace of a matrix?

For instance, I can express the above as $\large{\frac{\det(B)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \det(A_i)}}$, where $B$ is the diagonal matrix with $b_i$s along the diagonal, and $A_i$ is $B$ but with the ith diagonal element replaced by $a_i$.

Is there a way to keep going and simplify it further?

Comment: Its also $1/\mathrm{tr}(AB^{-1})$ where $B$ is as you say and $A=\mathrm{diag}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$..

Comment: Hmm, that's true but not particularly useful.  So maybe I limit this to just determinants?

Comment: Being unaware of what you are planning to do with this, I'm not able to judge that thought.

Comment: I'm trying to plug holes, basically.  If $b_i \rightarrow 0$ for some i, then the final inverse sum should approach 0 as well, but in practice I lose numerical precision.  I was wondering if there was a way to express the above in terms of the determinant of a matrix, with no divisions, such that $b_i = 0$ would give me the determinant of a singular matrix and spit out 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to come up with this:

$$B = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
b_1 \\
 & b_2 \\
 &  & b_3 \\
 &  & & b_4 \\
 &  & & & 1\\
\end{array}\right)$$

$$C = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
b_1 & b_2 &  &  & \\
 & b_2 & b_3 &  & \\
 &  & b_3 & b_4 & \\
 &  & & b_4 & 1\\
a_1 & -a_2 & a_3 & -a_4 & 0\\
\end{array}\right)$$

$$ \large{\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac{a_i}{b_i} }} = \frac{\det(B)}{\det(C)}$$